# How to access the `ContentCaptureManager` data?

Tags: android, android-content-capture

Based on [ContentCaptureManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/contentcapture/ContentCaptureManager) docs

> Content capture provides real-time, continuous capture of application
> activity, display and events to an intelligence service that is
> provided by the Android system. The intelligence service then uses
> that info to mediate and speed user journey through different apps.
> For example, when the user receives a restaurant address in a chat app
> and switchs to a map app to search for that restaurant, the
> intelligence service could offer an autofill dialog to let the user
> automatically select its address.

I would like to provide useful tips for the users of my app using the data collected by the `ContentCaptureManager`, just like the Maps example.

- How can I access the `ContentCaptureManager` data?
- Is there any known scenarios for tips, like addresses mentioned by the Maps example?